The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/camel-neeraj/sysmontask/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file
sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://downloads.1password.com/linux/debian/amd64 stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Hit:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                              
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                               
Hit:6 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                                                       
Hit:7 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                            
Hit:8 http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease                                                                                          
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                             
Hit:10 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                  
Ign:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/camel-neeraj/sysmontask/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/camel-neeraj/sysmontask/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/camel-neeraj/sysmontask/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.


I run sudo apt update and I get that
enter image description here
Please help

If you search this site you will find many questions same as yours. No release file.

Does this answer your question? What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?

PPAs or Personal Package Archives remember only get security checks IF YOU MAKE THEM.  Did you check to see if it was still maintained & trustworthy for your release...  If you need to check, you can explore links you provided in your question too.

ppa:camel-neeraj/sysmontask was last updated 128 weeks ago. Latest ubuntu version it was built for was Ubuntu 21.10 impish indri.
